# Laravel - database query convention/standard practice

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Something I've noticed about Laravel's eloquent models is that it seems to run a separate query for relationships.  Say you had an Employee model with 4 different relationships Department, Client, Store, and Manager.

Now, say you're displaying a list of all employees in your view in a table:

```
@foreach($employees as $employee)
    <tr>
        <td> {{$employee->department->name}} </td>
        <td> {{$employee->client->name}} </td>
        <td> {{$employee->store->name}} </td>
        <td> {{$employee->manager->name}} </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Every time $employees->relationship->whatever is called, it does a call to the database.  Why?  If you're displaying 100 employees, you'd be running 400 queries.

My question is: What's a good way to do this?  Use the query builder and do joins rather than use Eloquent?  Use CakePHP instead?  Haha.

Comment: Look to [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: You've miscounted here if you're eager loading, employees with 4 relationships would be 5 queries, no matter how many employee records were returned; and while not necessarily as efficient as a join, the code is a lot cleaner

Comment: Well, that was easier than expected lol.  Thanks a lot dudes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @watcher mentioned, [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) allows you to specify linked tables to load at the time of your first query. So, your controller would contain something like:

```
Employee::with('Department', 'Client', 'Store', 'Manager')->get();
```

This will select the employees along with their attributes.